# Uber mode configuration settings aligned but jobs do not execute in uber mode

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

According to documentation from [Hortonworks](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.15/bk_using-apache-hadoop/content/uber_jobs.html), the way to execute Hadoop jobs in "*uber mode*", is to configure one's `maprep-site.xml` settings like so:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
     <value>yarn</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.job.ubertask.enable</name>
     <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.job.ubertask.maxmaps</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.job.ubertask.maxreduces</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>mapreduce.job.ubertask.maxbytes</name>
     <value>134217728</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

For `mapreduce.job.ubertask.maxbytes`, I didn't really know what to put, I copied it from the `dfs.block.size` parameter in `hdfs-site.xml` and full disclosure I didn't really know what value to put there.

```
<property> 
    <name>dfs.block.size</name> 
    <value>134217728</value> 
    <description>Block size</description> 
</property>
```

Initially that block size was allocated according to my hunch that one of the reasons my job was failing was that the input data- which needs to be atomic (in the sense that it can't be broken up and fed into the mapper piecemeal)- was being split up in HDFS.

So nevertheless, despite the fact that these settings have been configured in such a way that the Hortonworks documentation, and others, would have one believe is sufficient to execute the job in "uber mode", the job does **not** in fact execute in that mode, as you can see below:

[image]

Is there something wrong with the settings as I've configured them that is preventing my job from executing in uber mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those configuration settings in the OP are OK- the thing about `uber mode` is that you can only have a single input file, not multiple- as it was before. See here:

```
17/10/12 20:42:42 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
17/10/12 20:42:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
17/10/12 20:42:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1507833515636_0005
17/10/12 20:42:44 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1507833515636_0005
17/10/12 20:42:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1507833515636_0005/
17/10/12 20:42:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1507833515636_0005
17/10/12 20:42:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1507833515636_0005 running in uber mode : true
```

or, straight from the horse's mouth:

[image]